# Sync local branch with remote branch EGit

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

I am using Git to share my code with my team and Eclipse as my IDE. I have installed the EGit plugin for Git functionality. The problem is that I am not sure what the correct steps to sync my local branch with the remote one are (something like: 1. Right click on your repository and  team->fetch 2. Pull 3. and so on...).

Currently I know that first I have to fetch (this will update my remote branch) and next I need to pull. Let's say there is a conflict between the remote and local branch; how should I resolve it?

I have read a lot of tutorials on the net, but it seems that my case is too obvious to explain elaborately.

Comment: briefly, I cannot do more since I hate egit with a passion: `fetch`, `merge` (not pull), resolve conflicts (with the merge tool in eclipse or by hand) then `git add` the resolved files and `commit`. I don't recommend using an IDE plugin for git, especially if you are new to git.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Currently I know that first I have to fetch (this will update my remote branch) next I need to pull

No, you can [pull directly](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Pulling_New_Changes_from_Upstream_Branch): it combines a fetch and a merge.

Any merge conflict that might arise during a pull will be handle [like any other merge](http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2011/05/30/merging-branches-in-eclipse-git-egit/)

> If your merge resulted in conflicts (note the red symbols on the file icons), you will have to resolve these manually. Open the conflicting files and scroll to the conflicting changes marked with “<<<<<<<”.

[image]

> After you are finished the manual part of the merge, you will have to tell Git that the conflicts are resolved. To do so, Add the files and Commit to complete your merge.

Comment: do I need to configure something before (I have 2 branches master and COR)

Comment: @VladIoffe you only need to be on the right local branch, which will be impacted by the merge of the upstream branch you will select